# Confirmation process for Yahoo Group membership

Tags: yahoo-groups

I invited someone to join Yahoo! groups. They emailed the -subscribe address and their request appeared in the Management section under "email activity". Even though I invited them first, will they still get an email message from Yahoo! asking them to confirm their membership?